# can openAi api be used to build virtual assistant and chatbot with personalized dataset?

Tags: openai-api

I am trying to make a fitness and e-commerce related web project where I want to integrate a chatbot and virtual assistant which will assist in making suggestions and recommendations to user regarding workouts ... I am a beginner to all of this and don't know much

I haven't actually tried anything yet...and this is supposed to be my final-year project

Comment: Look up Fine Tuning

Comment: If you have some experience in Python then [langchain](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain) is a great place to start with Large Language Models (LLM).

Comment: Now you can. https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/overview